# Unlocking an Access Database?

Tags: ms-access

So, I just finished working on a database in Access. And I was locking it down so the end users can't ruin it.

In the VBA code on load I included:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

I also had already locked out all the shortcuts and menu options using the general menu tab.

So, now I find myself going back to document the Database and... well I think you get the point, there must be someway of unlocking it from this state, but the question is how? My understanding is that all VBA code is locked in the .accdb file, and so inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is hold Shift+ double Click when you open the database as that will bypass all startup options. Which is nice to know.

So I hope this helps someone else in my shoes some day.

Comment: You can also stop bypassing `SHIFT+ENTER`. So, end user can't open it in design mode. Also `.accde` is best for distribution to end users.

Comment: Thank you for that, I am a complete, or near complete, Access noob, and the idea of compiling the database never even glimmered in the back of my head, wasn't aware it could even be done. Definitely going to make that change as soon as my documentation is done.